TinyMCE stopped displaying after working for a month
I've seen a few other posts on this topic but none of them actually solved my problem.
In one page (for the page header) I have this
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/mysupersecretkey/tinymce/7/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

But in the main page, I have the following code.
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#basic-example',
        height: 500,
        plugins: [
            'advlist', 'autolink', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview',
            'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'code', 'fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime', 'media', 'table', 'help', 'wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | ' +
            'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
            'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
            'removeformat | help',
        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px }'
    });
</script>

<div class="row mb-3">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
    <div classs="col-sm-6">
        <textarea id="basic-example"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

The editor used to display and now does not. Now, I only get the normal textarea.
The code is based on this sample from Tiny.
Then I went to my billing system to see if I am over the 1,000 loads per month and I see I am not even close.

So, TinyMCE used to work then just stopped working (seemingly without warning). The original code is not the above. Rather, it was the following:
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea.tinyEditor",
        plugins: 'image',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table mergetags | addcomment showcomments | spellcheckdialog a11ycheck typography | align lineheight | checklist numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat',
        tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
});
</script>

With the textarea line being
<textarea rows="30" class="tinyEditor form-control" name="description"></textarea>

As you can see, the selector was matching the class. Again, this worked, until it stopped working. Then I changed to the code you see above which depends on the ID as I saw on their docs website today.
I feel I must be missing something simple.
